# What I need to learn to build robots

Tags: artificial-intelligence, embedded-systems, first-robotics

What subjects are involved in robotics. If I want to build robots then what necessary things I need to learn consecutively as a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give you an answer that is similarly broad to your question:
Mechanical engineering, electrical engineering, control theory or computer science are a good start.

To give a more in-depth answer, you would have to tell us a little bit more. For starters, are you interested in robotics as a hobby or study, and what is your background? Is there any specific field of robotics that interests you?

Comment: My background is Computer Science and I'm interested in embedded systems especially intelligent systems that involves sensors